# How can I work with Upload File Dialog pop-ups from the .NET WebBrowser control?

Tags: .net, dialog, browser, save, sendkeys

I'm using the .NET `WebBrowser` control in C# to automate working with a website.  The page has a button control that opens the `WebBrowser` control's "Upload File" dialog to upload a file to the site.  However, I cannot seem to find any Object Model / Class Libraries for working with this File dialog directly?  This seems to be a standard MS windows file browser dialog, so I'm hoping there is a way to work with it directly.  Also, main thread execution of my application halts while this dialog is open in the WebBrowser control, so it has been particularly troublesome for me.

Ideally, I would like to send a file name path to the dialog and click the "open" button using code calls to the dialog directly, but I cannot seem to find a way to do this through an object model.  I do have a workaround that will work **sometimes** (if the timing is just right and the moon and all the stars are aligned perfectly) using SendKeys() before this dialog opens, but this is just a hack in the long run and only works intermittently.  I need something that will work in all cases.

Does anyone have any ideas about how I can work directly with the "Upload File" dialog that is generated by the .NET `WebBrowser` control?

Comment: Starting with "hello folks", and other forms of greetings is just not necessary as well for greetings and best wishes part. This community is more oriented to questiones to be answered, everything else is just redundant. I edited your post because in previous time I also made the same mistakes and was "scolded" by moderators :)

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for would pose such a huge gaping security hole it will *never* happen.

What you can do instead is use the `WebClient.UploadFile` method, or HttpWebRequest with the proper ContentType and RequestStream content.